# What is correct way to use in memory sqlite (System.Data.Sqlite) database with c++\cli?

Tags: sqlite, c++-cli, in-memory-database

I observe some type of memory leak using in-memory database with System.Data.Sqlite.

I have my own c++\cli project. Basic workflow is:

- Open XML file.
- Write it's data into in-memory database.
- Do some weird stuff.
- Load next XML file.

I have an sqlite wrapper class to handle database connection and perform queries. Since database must be created in memory i have SQLiteConnection member in this class.

```
ref class sql_wrapper{
    ...
    SQLiteconnection^ db;
    ...
}
```

When i'm opening connection i'm doing this (sort of)

```
void sql_wrapper::open_connection(string db_path){       
   db = gcnew SQLiteConnection();
   db->ConnectionString = db_path; //db_path = "Data Source=:memory:"
   db->open();
}
```

After that i'm loading information from xml file and do everything i need with this info. To execute query i generate `std::string` and then proceed it with function similar to this:

```
void sql_wrapper::execute_statement(string statement){
    SqliteCommand ^stm = db->CreateCommand();
    stm->CommandText = gcnew System::String(statement.c_str());
    stm->ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

So i don't have any adapter or command that needs to be Dispose.
Before opening the next file i'm closing the connection with this function:

```
void sql_wrapper::close_connection(){
    db->close();
    delete db;
}
```

Every source i found told that closing the connection should be enough to delete database from memory since "db" is the only one connection to it. But because of some reason database stays in the memory and then i'm loading next file my program "eats" more memory.

The "delete db" line is my last attempt to solve this problem. Didn't happen.

I also tried to add `System::GC::Collect()` in combination with `System::GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` into the `close_connection()` function but it didn't help.

Right now i have no idea what i'm doing wrong. Asking for help.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You say "don't have any adapter or command that needs to be Dispose", yet the code listed just before that includes a SqliteCommand object.

Comment: @CPerkins  I though that it should be deleted automatically then i'm going out of this function. But obviously it wasn't the case. It was a major contributor in memory leak actually. I still have to find other places where memory leaks but it's already so much better. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I only program in C# with .Net and don't know the ins-and-outs of C++-CLI.  With native .Net languages you're correct that the Dispose method would be called automatically when the local variable was terminated.  But even in those languages it is best practice to call Close/Dispose explicitly or wrap it in a "using" statement.  I suppose that in C++ those methods must be called explicitly, just as with closing the database object.  (FYI, the .Net System.Data.SQLite implementation is just interop calls to a C library.)